# Javascript array contains/includes sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, contains, indexof

I need to check if an array contains another array. The order of the subarray is important but the actual offset it not important. It looks something like this:

```
var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 

var sub = [777, 22, 22];
```

So I want to know if `master`  contains `sub` something like:

```
if(master.arrayContains(sub) > -1){
    //Do awesome stuff
}
```

So how can this be done in an elegant/efficient way?

Comment: Before doing it in an elegant way - implement it somehow first. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no elegant way in JS for your problem. You would better to look at JS libraries such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: "You have to look at libraries" --- that's too pessimistic, really.

Comment: is it rigth, that you want to have in the right order found 777 ... 22... 222 in the master array?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, the order is important

Answer (score 12):

With a little help from [`fromIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) parameter

This solution features a closure over the index for starting the position for searching the element if the array. If the element of the sub array is found, the search for the next element starts with an incremented index.

```js
function hasSubArray(master, sub) {
    return sub.every((i => v => i = master.indexOf(v, i) + 1)(0));
}

var array = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3];

console.log(hasSubArray(array, [777, 22, 22]));
console.log(hasSubArray(array, [777, 22, 3]));
console.log(hasSubArray(array, [777, 777, 777]));
console.log(hasSubArray(array, [42]));
```

Comment: `sub=[777, 22, 3]` returns true. Is that intentional? OP did say "actual offset it not important" but I'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: I'm asking you if your code intentionally matches that, because just looking at your example I would have expected `[777,22,22]` has to be contiguous in the master array, but that's not the case.

Comment: You've got another issue in there actually. It should `index = i + 1` to prevent double-matching on the same character. Otherwise `[777, 777, 777]` also matches!

Comment: @mpen, ad1 (`[777, 22, 3]`): yes, it is intentional, because `22` has a greater index than `777` and `3` ahs a greater index of `22`. ad2 (`[777, 22, 22]`): that is `true`. ad3 (`[777, 777, 777]`): you are right, the found index has to be incremented.

Answer (score 6):

```
var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 

var sub = [777, 22, 22]; 

console.log(master.join(',').includes(sub.join(',')))

//true
```

You can do this by simple `console.log(master.join(',').includes(sub.join(',')))` this line of code using include method

Comment: If the order is not important for you, you should first sort the arrays:

var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 

var sub = [777, 22, 22]; 

console.log(master.sort().join(',').includes(sub.sort().join(',')))

Comment: This will also return `true` for `[77, 22 ,22]`, `[7, 22, 2]`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It’s surprising how often this is implemented incorrectly.

What we’re looking for is a *substring* in the mathematical sense.

> In mathematics, a **[sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence)** is an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed and order matters.

> In mathematics, a **[subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)** of a given sequence is a sequence that can be derived from the given sequence by deleting some or no elements without changing the order of the remaining elements.

> A subsequence which consists of a consecutive run of elements from the original sequence, such as ⟨ B, C, D ⟩ from ⟨ A, B, C, D, E, F ⟩ is a **[substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)**.

Note that a “string”, here, can consist of any element and is not limited to Unicode code-point sequences.

Effectively all previous answers have one of many possible flaws:

- The string concatenation approach (`array1.toString().includes(array2.toString())`) fails when your array elements have commas. (Example: `[ "a", "b" ]` does *not* contain `[ "a,b" ]`).
- Some implementations check beyond array bounds. (Example: `[ "3" ]` does *not* contain `[ "3", undefined ]`, just because `array[1]` reports `undefined` for both).
- Some implementations fail to handle repetition correctly.
- Some implementations aren’t checking for substrings (in the mathematical sense) correctly, but for subsets or subsequences or something else.
- Some implementations don’t account for the empty array. The empty string is the substring of every string.

### Check if an array constitutes a “substring” of another array

Right off the bat, this handles the empty array correctly.

Then, it builds a list of candidate starting indexes by matching against the first element of the potential subarray.

[Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first candidate where [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) element of the slice matches index by index with the full array, offset by the candidate starting index.
The checked index also has to exist within the full array, hence [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn).

```js
const isSubArray = (full, slice) => {
    if(slice.length === 0){
      return true;
    }

    const candidateIndexes = full
        .map((element, fullIndex) => ({
          matched: element === slice[0],
          fullIndex
        }))
        .filter(({ matched }) => matched),
      found = candidateIndexes
        .find(({ fullIndex }) => slice.every((element, sliceIndex) => Object.hasOwn(full, fullIndex + sliceIndex) && element === full[fullIndex + sliceIndex]));

    return Boolean(found);
  };

console.log(isSubArray([], []) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0 ], []) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, undefined ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 0, 1, 1, 1 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ "a", "b" ], [ "a,b" ]) === false);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This has quadratic complexity, yes.
There might be more efficient implementations using [Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) or [Ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29).
You might also want to [research some efficient substring search algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40565766/4642212) and try to apply them to this problem.

### Get the index of the found “substring”, or `-1` if not found

It’s basically the same code, but with `return true;` replaced by `return 0;`, and `return Boolean(found);` replaced by `return found?.fullIndex ?? -1;`.

```js
const findSubArrayIndex = (full, slice) => {
    if(slice.length === 0){
      return 0;
    }

    const candidateIndexes = full
        .map((element, fullIndex) => ({
          matched: element === slice[0],
          fullIndex
        }))
        .filter(({ matched }) => matched),
      found = candidateIndexes
        .find(({ fullIndex }) => slice.every((element, sliceIndex) => Object.hasOwn(full, fullIndex + sliceIndex) && element === full[fullIndex + sliceIndex]));

    return found?.fullIndex ?? -1;
  };

console.log(findSubArrayIndex([], []) === 0);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0 ], []) === 0);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === 1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0, 1, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ]) === -1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === -1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, undefined ]) === -1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ]) === 1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === 2);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 0, 1, 1, 1 ]) === -1);
console.log(findSubArrayIndex([ "a", "b" ], [ "a,b" ]) === -1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### Semi-acceptable alternative: JSON

JSON-encoding both arrays might be a viable strategy as well.
Here, the surrounding `[`…`]` of the potential subarray need to be removed, then an `includes` will tell you if the JSON string is included in the other JSON string.
This works — as opposed to the simple string concatenation or `join` approach — because JSON has delimiters that cannot appear verbatim in the encoded elements; if they do appear in the original elements, they’d be correctly escaped.

The caveat is that this won’t work for values that are not encodable in JSON.

```js
const isSubArray = (full, slice) => JSON.stringify(full)
    .includes(JSON.stringify(slice).replaceAll(/^\[|\]$/g, ""));

console.log(isSubArray([], []) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0 ], []) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, undefined ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ]) === true);
console.log(isSubArray([ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 0, 1, 1, 1 ]) === false);
console.log(isSubArray([ "a", "b" ], [ "a,b" ]) === false);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just came up with quick thought , but efficiency depends on size of the array

```
var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3];
var sub = [777, 22, 22];

if ((master.toString()).indexOf(sub.toString()) > -1 ){
    //body here
}
```

Comment: This is actually the solution I went with in my implementation and I like it since it simple to understand. But I don't feel like it actually solves the problem because of two reasons: it could use prototype on array and I should get the actual index in the array (and not the string). Thanks!

Comment: What if `var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 224, 22, 6, 77, 3]; var sub = [777, 22, 22];`? This would be very dangerous.

Comment: @deblocker it could be something like `someArray.map(value => value.toString()).join(";")` so that the string would be delimited, avoiding false matches.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to match subset/sub-array

```
const master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 

const sub1 = [777, 44, 222]; 
const sub2 = [777, 18, 66]; 

sub1.every(el => master.includes(el));  // reture true
sub2.every(el => master.includes(el));  // return false
```

Comment: _“The order of the subarray is important”_ — You totally ignore the order.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is important, it has to be an actually sub-array (and not the subset of array) and if the values are strictly integers then try this

```
console.log ( master.join(",").indexOf( subarray.join( "," ) ) == -1 )
```

for checking only values check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/cnggzqL6/) (uses no third party libraries)

```
var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 

var sub = [777, 22, 22]; 

function isSubset( arr1, arr2 )
{
    for (var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++)
    {
        if ( arr1.indexOf( arr2[i] ) == -1 )
        {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
console.log( isSubset( master, sub ) );
```

There are faster options explained [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-an-array-is-subset-of-another-array-set-1/) as well.

Comment: @zerkms Why you say so? it is working. It outputs 'true'

Comment: Well, for my example it should have returned `false`

Comment: @zerkms got it. take your point. Trying to come up with one now which can handle multiple instances of same value.

Comment: This fails to account for repetitions in the subarray.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **filter** and **indexOf** like this:

Note: This code works in case we do not cover the order in sub array.

```
Array.prototype.arrayContains = function (sub) {
  var self = this;
  var result = sub.filter(function(item) {
    return self.indexOf(item) > -1;
  });
  return sub.length === result.length;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j6yfe1ne/).

**UPDATED:** Return index of sub array inside master (cover order in sub array)

```
Array.prototype.arrayContains = function(sub) {
  var first;
  var prev;
  for (var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    var current = this.indexOf(sub[i]);
    if (current > -1) {
      if (i === 0) {
        first = prev = current;
        continue;
      } else {
        if (++prev === current) {
          continue;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return first;
}
```

Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nguyentk/p3nrqkLw/6/)

Comment: I like that you used prototype and that it's simple. If you can get it to return the array indexOf I'll be willing to accept as answer.

Comment: This doesn’t return anything for empty subarrays. `[1, 2, 2].arrayContains([2, 2])` should be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Misunderstood question initially.

```
function arrayContainsSub(arr, sub) {
        var first = sub[0],
            i = 0,
            starts = [];

        while (arr.indexOf(first, i) >= 0) {
            starts.push(arr.indexOf(first, i));
            i = arr.indexOf(first, i) + 1;
        }

        return !!starts
                    .map(function(start) {
                        for (var i = start, j = 0; j < sub.length; i++, j++) {
                            if (arr[i] !== sub[j]) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (j === sub.length - 1 && arr[i] === sub[j]) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        };

                    }).filter(function(res) {
                        return res;
                    }).length;
    }
```

This solution will recursively check all available start points, so points where the first index of the sub has a match in the array

---

**Old Answer** Kept in case useful for someone searching.

`if(master.indexOf(sub) > -1){
    //Do awesome stuff
}`

Important to remember that this will only match of `master` literally references `sub`. If it just contains an array with the same contents, but references a different specific object, it will not match.

Comment: `arrayContainsSub([], [])` and `arrayContainsSub([ 3 ], [])` should be `true`. `arrayContainsSub([ 3, 4, 4 ], [ 4, 4, undefined ])` should be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I am preserving the order of sub-array. Means, the elements of sub-array should be in Consecutive order. If there is any extra element while comparing with the master, it will be false.

I am doing it in 3 steps:

1. Find the index of the first element of `sub` in the `master` and store it an array `matched_index[]`.
2. for each entry in `matched_index[]` check if each element of `sub` is same as `master` starting from the `s_index`. If it doesn't match then return `false` and break the for loop of sub and start next for-loop for next element in `matched_index[]`
3. At any point, if the same `sub` array is found in `master`, the loop will break and return true.

```js
function hasSubArray(master,sub){

    //collect all master indexes matching first element of sub-array
    let matched_index = [] 
    let start_index = master.indexOf(master.find(e=>e==sub[0]))
    
    while(master.indexOf(sub[0], start_index)>0){
        matched_index.push(start_index)
        let index = master.indexOf(sub[0], start_index)
        start_index = index+1
    } 

    let has_array //flag
    
    for(let [i,s_index] of matched_index.entries()){
        for(let [j,element] of sub.entries()){
            if(element != master[j+s_index]) {
                has_array = false
                break
            }else has_array = true
        }
        if (has_array) break
    }
    return has_array
}

var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3];

console.log(hasSubArray(master, [777, 22, 22]));
console.log(hasSubArray(master, [777, 22, 3]));
console.log(hasSubArray(master, [777, 777, 777]));
console.log(hasSubArray(master, [44]));
console.log(hasSubArray(master, [22, 66]));
```

Comment: `hasSubArray(master, [])` should be `true`; `hasSubArray(master, [ 3, undefined ])` should be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my offering. It seems to work nicely. First it looks through the whole master array for the first element in the sub array and keeps a list of candidates. Then it checks every candidate to see if the elements that follow match the sub array

```
const findSub = (master, sub) => {
  const candidates = [];
  const found = [];
  master.forEach((element, i) => {
    if (element === sub[0]) {
      candidates.push(i);
    }
  });
  candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
    if (master.slice(candidate, candidate + sub.length).every((element, i) => element === sub[i])) {
      found.push(candidate);
    }
  });
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If run this snippet below it should work

```
x = [34, 2, 4];
y = [2, 4];
y.reduce((included, num) => included && x.includes(num), true);
```

EDIT: 
@AlexanderGromnitsky You are right this code is incorrect and thank you for the catch! The above code doesn't actually do what the op asked for. I didn't read the question close enough and this code ignores order. One year later here is what I came up with and hopefully this may help someone.

```
var master = [12, 44, 22, 66, 222, 777, 22, 22, 22, 6, 77, 3]; 
var sub = [777, 22, 22]; 
var is_ordered_subset = master.join('|').includes(sub.join('|'))
```

This code is somewhat elegant and does what op asks for. The separator doesn't matter as long as its not an int.

Comment: doesn't work: it should return `false` for `y==[4,2]`

Answer (score -1):

```html
  async function findSelector(a: Uint8Array, selector: number[]): Promise<number> {
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
      if (a[i] === selector[j]) {
        j++;
        if (j === selector.length) {
          return i - j + 1;
        }
      } else {
        j = 0;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: Why is this an async function? `findSelector([], [])` and `findSelector([ 2 ], [])` should be `true`.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and resolved it using sets.

```
function _hasSubArray( mainArray, subArray )
{
    mainArray = new Set( mainArray );
    subArray = new Set( subArray );

    for ( var element of subArray )
    {
        if ( !mainArray.has( element ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `_hasSubArray([23,34,45,56], [23,34,23]) // returns true, though should return false`

Answer (score -3):

Try using **every** and **indexOf**

```
var mainArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var subArr = [1, 2, 3]

function isSubArray(main, sub) {
    return sub.every((eachEle) => {
        return (main.indexOf(eachEle) + 1);
    });
}
isSubArray(mainArr, subArr);
```

Comment: That's a good option if you don't search for the exact order of a subarray. OP mentioned that `The order of the subarray is important`, but in your case also [1,2,4] returns true